# Hidden on Custom Breakpoint Breaks All Breakpoints' Display Value in Tailwind

Tags: css, tailwind-css

[Here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/UrrQSPyvos) is the Tailwind Play code.

I have a configuration as below, mind the custom breakpoint:

```js
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  darkMode: "media", // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        xs: "320px", // here i have xs
      },
      colors: {
        orange: colors.orange,
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

Then I have some elements as below:

```html
<div class="bg-gray-500 xs:hidden sm:hidden md:flex">
  <h1>foo</h1>
</div>
```

I want the `div` to display on screens above `md`, otherwise it should be hidden.

The weird thing about the code above is this totally works with built-in breakpoint, `sm`. For example, if you remove `xs:hidden` in Tailwind Play. You will see the behavior I want to have.

However, I also want to include `xs:hidden`. Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance.

---

## Environment

```json
"postcss": "^7.0.39",
"tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat@^2.2.17"
```

Using with React.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To hide and element until a specific width use `hidden` to hide the element and another display class with responsive modifier (e.g. `md:flex`) to show it again.

So basically this should fit your needs:

```
<div class="bg-gray-500 hidden md:flex">
  <h1>foo</h1>
</div>
```

See https://play.tailwindcss.com/Nb0QOhn9E7 for a working snippet.

Combining a responsive hidden (e.g. `xs:hidden`) and with another responsive display class (e.g. `md:flex`) doesnt work as the specifity of both css selectors is the same (both use a single class selector inside a mediaquery) so the `md:flex` does not overwrite it.

Therefore use non-responsive `hidden` (single class selector) which is less specific then `md:flex` (single class selector inside a mediaquery) so it gets overwritten for `md` upwards.

Theres also a issue in tailwind-css github regarding this behaviour:
https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/841

Comment: Nice and useful, short and concise solved my problem as well.